# Calling a function within a function in a loop - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I didn't find a solution in "similar" questions. I like to call a function in a function in a loop. the solution will not be to set "parameters" in front of the function (def inner) I try to call. I like to call the "def inner" in the end of the loop. Thanks!

```py
    def meta1():
        def inner():
            print("hello inner2")
            parameters = {"Name": "XYZ","max_time": 35}
            return parameters

    def meta2():
        def inner():
            print("hello inner2")
            parameters = {"Name": "XXX","max_time": 25}
            return parameters
```

the loop over the functions

```py
    for func in [meta1, meta2]:
        x = func()
        print(x['Name'])

        print("here is some other code between. The solution is not to change the functions!")


        print(func(inner())) #here i need some help, thanks
```

Comment: The question doesn't look clear. I don't see a body for the `inner` functions defined

Comment: Your formatting is broken ... is the body of inner() only the print?

Comment: please be more clear in what you want to achieve... and check indentation as your inner function now has no code in it

Comment: sorry to be not clear.  may mixed some things. i will try to explain what i achieve. @tim - no i will be a calculation.

Comment: The python you have used is a synax error. After def inner(), you must have indenting.

Comment: If you want to call the inner function from outside the outer function, return it (along with the other values you want to return).

Comment: Your question would be better if you gave output showing errors, and then you ask about the errors. Your question is not even valid Python.

Comment: @ tim. i changed the code back because i have to separate the dict parameters and the def printer. i also changed the names. because i mixed to much and def inner is confusing. may i try to give a complete new example. sorry!

Comment: Thank you wwii. i am new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear why you want/need to do this but if each `meta` also returns its inner function then it is easy.

```
def meta1():
    def printer():
        print("hello xyz")
    parameters = {"Name": "XYZ","max_time": 35}
    return parameters,printer

def meta2():
    def printer():
        print("hello xxx")
    parameters = {"Name": "XXX","max_time": 25}
    return parameters,printer

for func in [meta1, meta2]:
    x,inner = func()
    print(x['Name'])
    print("here is some other code between. The solution is not to change the functions!")
    print(inner())
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is not clear what you want to do, this code may help
You can copy and paste it into an Idle window, and run it.

The point of my answer is to introduce you to classes, which in Python may be the best fit for the level of abstraction you want. Classes are a major feature of Python, and when you learn about them you will also discover static members and so on. But for now ...

```
def meta1():
    def inner():
        print("hello inner2")
        parameters = {"Name": "XYZ","max_time": 35}
        return parameters


class Meta1ClassExample:
    def inner(self):
        print("hello inner2")
        parameters = {"Name": "XYZ","max_time": 35}
        return parameters




if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        meta1.inner()  #AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'inner'
    except AttributeError:
        print("As expected, looking for the inner function is an error")

    metaclass = Meta1ClassExample()
    p = metaclass.inner()
    print (p)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to use the inner functions outside meta1 and meta2, respectively, you can try something like this:

```
def meta1():
    def printer():
        print("hello xyz")
    parameters = {"Name": "XYZ","max_time": 35}
    return printer, parameters

def meta2():
    def printer():
        print("hello xxx")
    parameters = {"Name": "XXX","max_time": 25}
    return printer, parameters

for func in [meta1, meta2]:
    printer_fct, x = func()
    print(x['Name'])

    print("here is some other code between. The solution is not to change the functions!")


    print(printer_fct()) #here i need some help, thanks
```

Edit: In the last line, you would probably want a simple call to the function `printer_fct()`, since the application of `print` only outputs `None`  because `printer_fct()` does not return anything.